# Infinite loop (do - while)

Tags: infinite-loop, do-while

```
for(int m=0;m<=3;m++){
    for(int n=0;n<=3;n++){
        if(n>0){
            int c =n,t=1;
            do{
                t = up_key_no0(&puzz[c][m]);
                c--;
            }while(t==1||c>=0);
        }
    }
}
int up_key_no0(int *puzy){
    int *puzx = puzy -4;
    int down = *puzy;
    int up = *puzx;
    if(((down==up)||(up==0))&&down!=0){
        *puzx += *puzy;
        *puzy=0;
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Is The Following piece of code wrong? if Yes Then Reply. The Whole Code Cant Be Fit But puzz is a 2 dimensional array of 4X4

Comment: What is your code even trying to do before we just answer "Yes" or "No"?

Comment: I can't help but focus on the puzy.

Comment: Could you flag which language you are using? Could you also state what your code is supposed to be doing and what symptoms you are seeing?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError C, a puzy! I wish I could C#...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that language is this, but case it's like Java, a "for" should be like so:

```
for (var i=0;i<=3;i++) {

}
```

Your while maybe wrong. This "==" on the while should be "=".

```
while(t=1||c>=0) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your do-while loop can go out of the range of the table to the negative indices when the t is 1 and the c is 0. So maybe you should change the condition to `(t == 1 && c >= 0)` (and instead of or).